# opening other application causes status bar indent

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

So I have a feature in my app that allows for in app calling. It uses the phone number i have provided and calls using the iPhones phone app. The problem is that when i call somebody and hang up and go back to my app, there is an indent in the status bar. I have it so that an image is behind the status bar but when you hang up the call and go back to the app, the view controller is indented by 20 points and shows the background of the previous view controller. Here is my code and an image.

```
let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneDigit + phoneNumber)")
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
}
```

Image of the issue:
[image: Example image about what I'm talking about!]

Comment: have you added a constraint for the top of the image view to the top layout guide, or to the top of the screen?

Comment: @PranavKasetti yes I have and its 0. That red bar is the the previous view controller bleeding into the current one. It only happens when I hang up the call and go back to the app

Comment: why what do you think